# How to use sympy latex() write polynomials with increasing coefficients

Tags: python, sympy, polynomials

I want to use sympy `latex()` write polynomials with increasing coefficients. Please help me. Thanks!

This is my code

```py
import sympy as sp
x=sp.symbols('x')
print(sp.latex(3*x**2+2*x+4))
```

The result is: `3 x^{2} + 2 x + 4`

I want to get: `4 + 2 x + 3 x^{2}`